# Display a £ sign in Coldfusion charts

Tags: coldfusion, cfchart

Quite simple really, I want to display the British pound sign (£) in the yAxis title in a printed Coldfusion PNG chart.

Here's my code:

```
<cfchart xAxisTitle="Year" yAxisTitle="Cash Flow (£)" gridlines="6" showXGridlines="yes" showYGridlines="yes" showborder="no" format="png" seriesplacement="stacked" chartwidth="350" chartheight="200"> 
    <cfchartseries type="bar" seriesLabel="Saving" seriescolor="##434348">
        <cfset chartYear = 0>
        <cfloop list="#FORM.chartSaving#" index="value">
            <cfchartdata item="#chartYear#" value="#Round(value)#">
            <cfset chartYear = chartYear + 1>
        </cfloop>
    </cfchartseries> 
    <cfchartseries type="bar" seriesLabel="RHI" seriescolor="##7cb5ec">
        <cfset chartYear = 0>
        <cfloop list="#FORM.chartRHI#" index="value">
            <cfchartdata item="#chartYear#" value="#Round(value)#">
            <cfset chartYear = chartYear + 1>
        </cfloop>
    </cfchartseries>
</cfchart>
```

I've tried various combinations of £ and &##163; but nothing is displaying the £ sign.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Try putting `<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding = "Windows-1252" />` in the document.

Comment: Can you please give us a stand-alone repro case, none one that relies on form fields and data that we don't have? We should be able to copy and paste your example and run it locally. http://sscce.org/

Comment: *a stand-alone repro case* +1. In this specific case, simply posting the `<cfchart ...></cfchart>` tags would have done it. Yes, the chart would be empty, but that does not matter. That minimal code would be enough to produce a chart "title", which is the issue at hand.

Comment: Hi @Leigh, yeah, in this case it'd be fine. But it would benefit Pat to think about how we might go about troubleshooting their *next* problem. Also to weed out the cruft & pare back to just the problem domain is work - that *we* should not have to do - in itself. Also if the issue wasn't so obvious, it would be less obvious which part of the example code is completely irrelevant. It's the asker's job to provide a concise repro case.

Comment: @AdamCameron - quite right - I'll do better next time . . .

Comment: @Adam - True, but I think this was also a good opportunity to get people thinking about "weed[ing] out the cruft & par[ing] back to *just the problem domain*". This specific case is a great example of what is the bare minimum necessary to reproduce the issue and what code can be eliminated as not relevant to the problem. Ultimately, that helps them (more than us) both with troubleshooting and posting on S.O. Agreed, not every case is this simple, but it makes for a good illustration IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [chr()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e3b.html) with its decimal value:

```
<cfchart xAxisTitle="Year" yAxisTitle="Cash Flow #chr(163)#" ....>
```

If you want to *hard code* the literal £ character into the CF source file, be sure to set the file's encoding to UTF8. Otherwise, it will not be displayed correctly.

```
   <cfprocessingDirective pageEncoding="UTF-8" />
   <cfchart xAxisTitle="Year" yAxisTitle="Cash Flow (£)"  ....>
```

Comment: Confirmed that either of these options works for me, although are char codes about 127 guaranteed to have a specific rendering? I thought only 0-127 were standardised (as ASCII)? I think using the actual character (and setting the page encoding accordingly, if it's hard-coded in the file) is a better option.

Comment: Yeah, you are right about extended ascii codes. Due to CF's lousy handling of unicode strings, the simplest I have come up with is to build it from the hex code: `charsetEncode(binaryDecode("c2a3", "hex"), "utf-8")`

Comment: #chr(163)# cracked it :)

Comment: Yes, but as Adam pointed out, it is not *guaranteed* to render correctly on all systems :) So you should either a) hard code it and use cfprocessingDirective with UTF8 (the missing directive was why it did not work originally) or b) decode it from hex as [noted here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364543/display-a-%c2%a3-sign-in-coldfusion-charts/27365293?noredirect=1#comment43213406_27365293)